# Google Calendar API + Azure + intermittent Connection Timeout

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, google-calendar-api, azure-webjobs

We are using the Google Calendar API to retrieve calendar events periodically.  Running on an Azure Webjob (web app s3). Doesn't look like we getting anywhere need our quota limits with the Google Calendar API.

We are intermittently getting the error below. Normally if we retry then it works.  Seems to occur more often when we increase the number of Google Calendars we are retrieving events for.  They seem to happen in batches.  If we see 1 error then likely we will see another 10 fail but then the next 200 will work fine.  My guessing is were seeing a network error somewhere or hitting some limit (in Azure?).

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 216.58.194.170:443

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? Running into the same issue.

Comment: Sorry I did not.  Would be keen to know if you find a fix.  At the moment we just have retry logic if it fails.  Not a great solution, especially as our calendar count continues to grow.

Comment: Hey man, any news about this? Difficult to solve that problem. Maybe we can put our heads together and try a solution